# DSL Json @JsonAttribute not working for String

Tags: java, json

This is my Example class:

```
public class ABC{

private String stringInQuestion;
private Location  loc;

@JsonAttribute(ignore = true, mandatory = true, nullable = false)
    public String getstringInQuestion() {
        return loc.getLocationID();
    }
```

This attribute still shows up in my response. I do not want to serialize it. This was working fine with Jackson ignore (@JsonIgnore), however, we switched to DSL Json library for performance gains. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add a tag for the language you're working with. Looks like Java.

Comment: Added...Thanks!

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: dsl-json-java8, version 1.8.4